# Node, express, Monk, mongodb: 400 bad request error on post request. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: node.js, api, post, express, crud

I've been trying to get a simple nodejs API with CRUD functionality working. I'm using express, and 'monk' package for communicating with mongodb. I've successfully pulled data with a GET request.

I'm unable to get a post() function to work. I'm able to insert new documents to mongo when the insert request is called from a GET request that inserts a doc every time it's called. However, no matter what I do, with or without an actual insert request, my post is returning a 400.

Here's my route file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET hours page. (for users to submit hours) */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('entries');
    collection.find({}, /*{limit:20}, */function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('couldn\'t load entries');
        }
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

/* POST hours page. (for users to submit hours) */
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    if (!(req.body.job || req.body.code || req.body.hours)) {
        handleError(res, 'Invalid user input', 'Must complete input', 400);
    }
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('entries');
    var newEntry = req.body;

    collection.insert(newEntry, function (err, docs) {
        if (err){
            handleError(res, err.message, 'Failed to create new entry');
        }
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I really don't know why ever single post request is returning a 400. I'm thinking it's a problem with my main file, but it has barely been altered from the initial express generated file.

Comment: It turns out this code is working just fine. For some reason I thought it would be smart to send raw JSON in my post rather than x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `if` condition is wrong. `!(req.body.job || req.body.code || req.body.hours)` should be `!(req.body.job && req.body.code && req.body.hours)`.
And are you sure you have really post anything? Check the `Content-Type` of your requests, which should be  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;`.
  I recommand using `supertest` to test your app. The usage is very simple.

```
import request = require("supertest");
import should = require("should");
import app = require("../youApp");

describe("POST /foo", () => {
  it("should post something", done => {
    request(app)
        .post("/foo")
        .send({job: "my job", code: "...", "hours"})
        .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

## Somthing more

1. replace `var` with `const` .
2. use arrow function instead of `function(req, res)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!I tried removing this if block completely. I don't think the problem is with the code itself - I've tried everything including removing all of the code completely. I'm making posts using POSTMAN. I'm sending a raw JSON to the correct address. Even with a blank post, it error 400s.